# How to determine whether my GWT app is running inside a frame/iframe or not?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I'm working on a GWT application, which should behave in a slightly different manner when it is running inside a frame and when running directly in a browser window.
The question is: how to determine at runtime whether we're in a frame or in a window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap a bit of javascript into [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

```
public static native boolean isFrame() /*-{
    return ($wnd!=$wnd.top);
}-*/;
```

Comment: Ups. Two mistakes: equality operator and return type. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but looking at the javadoc you can try something like:

```
RootPanel.getBodyElement().getParentElement().getTagName()
```

and see if it's an iframe or whatever tag you need